# how to Use NOT IN clause in Google App Engine Data Store

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I want to run this query in GAE's GQL.

```
select * from Content where masterContentTypeId not in (select id from MasterContentType)
```

***here In the innner query, "id" is integer type, generated by GAE.***
but It is giving error `GQL query error: Encountered "not" at line 1, column 49. Was expecting one of: "contains" ... "has" ... "is" ... "=" ... "<" ... "<=" ... ">" ... ">=" ... "." ... "(" .`

How can I make correct query?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Google Datastore and GQL doesn't support neither `NOT IN` queries, nor subqueries.

There're GQL grammar for reference: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#grammar

Comment: is there any alternate for this?

Comment: I guess you can split it into few independent queries. One to get `masterContentTypes` ids, then all `Content` with distinct `masterContentTypeId`, and compare this two lists in your code. Or you can iterate whole `Content` table.

Comment: Can u help me here. if i run the query "select id from MasterContentType" in GQL, then why the "id" is not recognized as column. This column shows as "ID/Name" in table as it is key, and if I run "select * from <Kind>" it works fine. Means how can I display only Id column using query?

Comment: try `select __key__ from ...` instead